# How to add HTML to google maps as overlay

Tags: html, google-maps

I am trying to add a simple HTML snippet into my google maps placed near a location marker, but haven't found a good example or a documentation helping me out.
I read this documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple
and its close to my expectations, but I'd need some custom styles, change the position, hiding the arrow, and stuff like that...

Here the gmap Code:

```
var gps = {lat: 48.2494324, lng: 16.3417493}
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), {
        center: gps,
        zoom: 15
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: gps,
        map: map
    });
};
```

Any hints? Possible with infowindow? Is there another "easy" way I haven't found yet? I'll appreciate some example codes, but hints are okay aswell, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about having two divs in one div and setting the z-index and position css settings?

```css
.container
{
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.container .google-map-container
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;  
  width: 100%; /* Might not be required depending on google map element */
}

.container .snippet
{
  /* important */
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;  
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 15;
  display: block; /* might get away without this */
  
  /* style */
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="google-map-container">
    <!-- Google map element goes here -->
  </div>
  <div class="snippet">
    <h3>Info title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum info text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes. problem is, i don't care resizes and stuff like that but I need the info div related to a position. If you scroll inside the map the box should always be near my marker

Comment: Ah! Okay, I am with you now. Having a look at the info window options documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions) there doesn't seem to be much flexability. 

Have you tried adding a div with a Class and/or ID attribute(s) within the content and trying to expand that div with CSS to trying and override the info window? It's a long shot, but might work.

Comment: changed from using infoWindow to customOverlay, now i have full control over the styles, thx for your help